# Using SOAP MTOM with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

Having problem with finding any good resource(see tutorial/example) of how to utilize **SOAP** **MTOM** with **Node.js** There is some libraries(soap-node), but not for SOAP MTOM. As SOAP is pretty common and already bit old web service, I thought that is already done many times. Is there any suggestion of how to create **SOAP** call with attachment and receive answer with attachment as well in **Node.js**. Some tutorial or example?

Comment: https://github.com/yaronn/ws.js

Comment: I had look at this one as well, is there anything else than that? Something like soap-node but with MTOM supported, any experience?

Comment: https://www.example-code.com/nodejs/mtom_xop_attachment.asp

Comment: This one has some mystery Chilkat license, and using it in own projects will be questionable. But thanks any way. I just wondering is there some mature solutions for such pretty common thing?

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to use MTOM with node in the end ? ws.js documentation isn't cristal clear and the Chilkat thing definitely seems weird.

Comment: Yes, in the end I end up using this github.com/yaronn/ws.js Yaron approach, but sure I was taking it as reference and create on this base some peace of software that fulfill my needs. So just take it and spend some time with debugger, then grab soapUI and create samples with working messages, after that you will have to create some modifications and it should work just fine.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61761150/948938